# FOR command expands %~dpI to path with extra "\" not suitable for destination path of replace command

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

Problem: Output of FOR command expands %~dpI to a path with an extra \ at the end that is not suitable as a destination path for the REPLACE command.

Question: How to get rid of the extra \?

What I want to do: Copy file 1.txt to each sub-directory under C:\aaa if the file is newer.

Directory structure:

```
c:\aaa
c:\aaa\1
c:\aaa\2
...
```

Using:

```
FOR /R C:\aaa %I IN (1.txt) DO REPLACE c:\aaa\1.txt %~dpI /U /R
```

Sample Output:

```
c:\aaa>REPLACE c:\aaa\1.txt c:\aaa\1\ /U /R
Path not found - C:\aaa\1\
no files replaced

c:\aaa>REPLACE c:\aaa\1.txt c:\aaa\2\ /U /R
Path not found - C:\aaa\2\
no files replaced
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
REPLACE c:\aaa\1.txt c:\aaa /U /R /S
```

Why bother with the FOR/R?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Use `%~dpI..\%~nI`:

That would expand to:

```
c:\aaa\1\..\1
```

**Option 2**

Set an environment variable to the path, then grab all but the last character:

```
SET targetpath=C:\aaa\1\
ECHO %targetpath:~,-1%
```

That outputs:

```
C:\aaa\1
```

Answer (score 1):

Add only one point to your command:

`FOR /R C:\aaa %I IN (1.txt) DO REPLACE c:\aaa\1.txt %~dpI. /U /R`

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but DOS batch never is.  You can throw another `FOR` in there with the `/F` switch to process the name.  Here's what I ran:

```
FOR /R . %I IN (foo) DO @FOR /F "delims=" %N IN ("%~dpI.") DO @echo %~fN
```

That outputs every directory name from the current directory.  The `"delims="` is to include whitespace as valid characters.  The `%~dpI.` is a kludge to use that directory as a full path, then `%~fN` gives the complete directory name.

You can achieve a similar thing with the `DIR` command.  Try:

```
DIR /AD /S /B
```

So in fact:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %I IN ('dir /AD /S /B') do @echo %~fI
```

The exception is that the above does not include the base directory.

Comment: It's great that you put effort into it, but it looks unnecessarily long.